# How can I shrink activity to the size of its contents

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have an `Activity` that I want to use as a popup. I used the code below to make it work but I would like the `Activity` to adapt to the size of its contents. For example if the `Activity` has an `EditText` and a `Button` with a combined height of `40dp`, the `Activity` should have a height of `40dp`.

```
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*0.8),(int)(height*0.8));
```

Comment: You should use DialogFragment with custom view. Activity is not designed for this case.

Comment: I think you don't even need an activity for this. You can simple use `AlertDialog`

Answer (score 0):

Use a dialog theme, [such as `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html#Theme_AppCompat_Dialog).